# Sub Sonic 2.2 cache? problem

Tags: subsonic

I recently started playing around with SubSonic 2.2 (only 2.2 because I didn't find any Oracle t4 templates at the time).  That aside, I have been noticing that I can run a query on table a and field b will have a value of 1.  If I went into Sql Tools or Oracle Developer and changed field b to a value of 2, SubSonic's LoadByKey functions still returns an object with field b having a value of 1.

In case that is hard to read.

var id = "primary key";
x.LoadByKey(id);
Console.Write(x.b); -> yields 1

I can go change this value in another program and rerun the code and it is always 1 regardless.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think is that it's an app issue, or a driver-level issue. We don't implement any kind of caching.